# What am I doing wrong in this simple Python code?

Tags: python

-- My goal is to make a code where user has to enter temperature, then user has to enter unit (C or F), then I wanna show conversion to F if users type C and vice versa. what wrong here tell me please I am super new to python and learning it all day, thanks.

```
print("Lets convert from C to F/ F to C")
temp = int(input("enter the temperature: "))
unit = input("enter the unit (C or F)")
if unit == C:
    F = temp * 1.8 + 32
    print(temp +"C is equal to"+F +"F")
elif unit == F:
    C = temp / 1.8 - 32
    print(temp + "F is equal to" +C + "C")
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: You are presently comparing unit with the contents of a variable C rather than the string 'C'.  You need to change your condition to `if unit == 'C'` and the same for F.

Comment: C and F are not declared variables anywhere. What you want it to compare to the string "C" or "F".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to pay more attention to strings.

1. use string literals `'F'` and `'C'` (*not* bare `F` and `C`) in the `if` conditions.
2. explicitly convert `int` to `str` by using `str()`, when you concatenate an `int` and `str`. Or better, use f-string.

```py
print("Lets convert from C to F/ F to C")
temp = int(input("enter the temperature: "))
unit = input("enter the unit (C or F)")
if unit == 'C':
    F = temp * 1.8 + 32
    print(str(temp) +"C is equal to"+str(F) +"F")
elif unit == 'F':
    C = temp / 1.8 - 32
    print(str(temp) + "F is equal to" +str(C) + "C")
```

By the way, I am afraid the formula is a little bit off. Another version, in which I corrected the formula and used f-string, is as follows:

```py
print("Let's convert from °C to °F or °F to °C!")
temp = int(input("Enter the temperature: "))
unit = input("Enter the unit (C or F): ")
if unit.upper() == 'C':
    F = temp * 1.8 + 32
    print(f"{temp}°C is equal to {F}°F")
elif unit.upper() == 'F':
    C = (temp - 32) / 1.8
    print(f"{temp}°F is equal to {C}°C")
```

Comment: That's a good catch. An example of such an f string would be: `print(f"{temp} C is equal to {F} F")`

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Lets convert from C to F/ F to C")

temp = int(input("enter the temperature: "))
unit = input("enter the unit (C or F)")

if unit == "C": #small typo
    F = temp * 1.8 + 32
    print(str(temp) + "C is equal to" + str(F) + "F") # you cant do int + str
elif unit == "F":
    C = temp / 1.8 - 32
    print(str(temp) + "F is equal to" + str(C) + "C")
```